# Why dont we need the super keyword to help initialize the OrderedDict subclass?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Following is an implementation of a LRU cache using an OrderedDict. Why don't do we need to call `super().__init__()` here , for the class to be initialized as an OrderedDict object ? (The follow-up question would be when do we need to call `super().__init__()` perhaps)

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
class LRUCache(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        """
        :type capacity: int
        """
        self.capacity = capacity

    def get(self, key):
        """
        :type key: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if key not in self:
            return - 1
        
        self.move_to_end(key)
        return self[key]

    def put(self, key, value):
        """
        :type key: int
        :type value: int
        :rtype: void
        """
        if key in self:
            self.move_to_end(key)
        self[key] = value
        if len(self) > self.capacity:
            self.popitem(last = False)

# Your LRUCache object will be instantiated and called as such:
# obj = LRUCache(capacity)
# param_1 = obj.get(key)
# obj.put(key,value)
```

Answer (score 1):

At best, it's a harmless omission, assuming that `OrderedDict.__init__` and `dict.__init__` don't do anything useful. At worst, they *do* need to be called, or `LRUCache` might be used with multiple inheritance and `super().__init__` is needed to call a method in a class you don't even know about yet.

```
def __init__(self, capacity, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.capacity = capacity
```

See [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for a discussion on the use of keyword arguments when using `super` (especially when using it in `__init__`).